# Hex width in C printing not working properly?

Tags: c, printf

I'm printing out and array of three bytes like this:

`cmd_buf` is passed as a `const char *`

```
    for (ii = 0; ii<=2; ii++) {
        printf("byte[%0d] = %02x\n", ii, cmd_buf[ii]);
    }
```

But I'm seeing this:

```
# BUFFER IS b4a602
# byte[0] = ffffffb4
# byte[1] = ffffffa6
# byte[2] = 02
```

It works properly if I do this:

```
       printf("byte[%0d] = %02x\n", ii, (unsigned char) cmd_buf[ii]);
```

Shouldn't `%02x` be printing only two characters?  Why is it acting like this is an signed value?

Comment: It will print *from* two characters and up, that is will pad single digit numbers with `0`. *"Why is it acting like this is an signed value?"* - Because your `char` type is signed.

Comment: Aside `%02x` isn't to print 2 characters, but a *minimum* of 2 characters. If it wider then it breaks the field width rather than outputting an incorrectly truncated number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%x is int - it implicitly turned your signed char into a 4-byte to match.  use %hx for short and %hhx for char.  In your case, you likely meant to use %02hhx